# Can't use pip to install flask

Tags: python, command-line, flask, pip

I'm trying to install flask but I can't use `pip install flask` in the windows command line. I'm in the directory C:\Python35, where python is installed. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python, and it doesn't seem to be installing pip during the python installation. I'm not sure if i'm not installing Python right. Why can't I use pip?

Here is what i've tried

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Matt>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Matt>cd C:\python34
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Matt>cd C:\Python35

C:\Python35>pip install flask
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Python35>
```

UPDATE: I was able to "install" pip but I still can't use it. Here's my cmd.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Python35>python -m pip install package-name
Collecting package-name
  Downloading package_name-0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: package-name
  Running setup.py install for package-name ... done
Successfully installed package-name-0.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.

C:\Python35>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |################################| 1.3MB 147kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.1
Successfully installed pip-9.0.1

C:\Python35>pip install flask
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Python35>python pip install flask
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Python35>pip
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Python35>pip3
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Python35>
```

***SOLVED***

I had to use `python -m pip install flask` instead of just `pip install flask`

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Are you sure you are in the windows command line and not the python interpreter?

Comment: Yeah i'm in the windows command line